# How to notify a producer in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

i have a producer who sends messages on kafka and a consumer processes a business rule, but my producer needs to be notified when the consumer finishes processing the message. Does the consumer need to send a message on another topic when finished to notify the producer, or is there any other way to do it?

See if this image is correct.

[kafka flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r3h3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in mechanism in Kafka, because the idea of Kafka's design is to completely *decouple* producers and consumers.

Using a topic as a back channel should work. Of course, there are many other possible solutions, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can determine the consumer finishes processing all the message,just shut down the consumer and wait for some seconds.
Using a Zookeeper client to watch the consumer ZNode,when it removs,the client get notification and can transfer it to producer.But you may need communicating between the threads.
I don't know if it's right,but i think you can make a try.